# VBA to Python for loop/condition

Tags: python, vba

I am new to Python and I am trying to figure out the Python equivalent of VBA Cells command.

I am trying to be able to loop through all the rows in a Dataframe and replace the value given a condition. In VBA, the code would look something like this:

```
for i = 1 to 100  
if range.cells(i,1) <> "" then 
range.cells(i,1) = 100
end if 
next i
```

However, in Python I believe I need to use the df.iloc command but I cant seem to figure out how to iterate over rows and replace the value of the row based on a condition.

For example, in the dataframe below I would like to see the string 'answer' in d['test'] every time the right most digit in d['val_1'] == 4.

```
import pandas as pd
d = {'val_1': range(0,100), 'val_2': 4}
d = pd.DataFrame(d)
d['sum'] = d['val_1'] + d['val_2']
d['test'] = ""

for i in range(0,len(d)):
    if right(d.iloc[i,'val_1'],1) == 4:
    d.iloc[i,'test'] = 'answer'
```

Comment: How do you create your dataframe? Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of your dataframe and the expected output.

Comment: "I am trying to be able to loop through all the rows in a Dataframe and replace the value given a condition." Explicitly looping through a data-frame is generally your last resort. Instead, you should rely on built-in vectorized operations (probably involving `iloc` based indexing). Can you give a more clear example of what you are trying to do?